# HTML designer that works with CSS/Divs and not Table design?

Tags: html, css, designer

Is there some sort of HTML designer (WYSIWYG) available that allows me to draw the page and results with a page using DIVs / CSS and not TABLE design?

Comment: my two cent: please keep in mind that so-called div soup is in no way better than a table layout. Instead you should write semantically correct markup, which means that you use headers for headers, lists for lists, and so on. divs are only meant as the last resort if there is no other fitting tag

Comment: ... and use tables for tabular data. Nothing wrong with them being used for what they were designed for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [drawter.com](http://drawter.com) you can create layout in div css format.

Answer (score 2):

MS Visual Web Developer Express, its free and allows full WYSIWYG and code view HTML/CSS editing for pure (X)HTML or ASP.Net sites.

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#Visual_Studio_2010_Express_Downloads
http://www.microsoft.com/express/Express-2010/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of what you are asking of but if you are looking for a wysiwyg(what you see is what you get) editor Adobe Dreamweaver is probably the best but it's rather expensive. There are ton's of free wysiwyg`s however I don't use them so I only know of Dreamweaver.